# Azure storage account, make the file public with public link to download file

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have developed an app for a client with an azure database, I have never before worked with azure so I have no idea what I'm doing, I am using the .NETAutoUpdater package as the updater and require the update file to be a zip on a public link. Is there any to do this using Azure Storage Accounts --> Blobs and just make the blob public with a link? again I have no idea what I am doing in azure so any assistance will be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible. From the list of your blobs, click the grey dots at the end of the line and choose *"Change access level"*.

[image: View of the menu]

Then change the access level to *"Blob"*. Now open the blob container and select its properties view.

[image: The properties of the blob]

As you can see it shows an URL like `https://yourapp.blob.core.windows.net/yourblobcontainer`. Files that are placed in this container will be downloadable via that URL. E.g. if you have a file named `foo.bar` it'll be available at `https://yourapp.blob.core.windows.net/yourblobcontainer/foo.bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

It is actually fairly simple and straightforward to do. Simply set the ACL of the blob container containing your zip file to either `Blob` (recommended) or `Container` and the blobs inside that container will be publicly accessible.

You can set the ACL of the blob container on the portal, using any available storage explorers or programmatically.